# Is there a blank identifier in Python as there is in Golang?

Tags: python, go

For instance, I have a string that splits into 3 parts but I need just the first and third parts.

```
one, two, three = '1 2 3'.split()
```

After the above line, I would have to execute a "del" to remove it from variable list.

```
del(two)
```

Is there a way I can discard "two" immediately? Like"

```
one, _, three = '1 2 3'.split()
```

Additionally, **this is not a question about language semantics** which has been answered in the following question.

[What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

This is a question if Python runtime has that feature to remove the variable automatically.

Comment: Your code works, both lines. Can always save `s = '1 2 3'.split()` and do `one, three = s[0], s[-1]`

Comment: @RafaelC The question is about Golang

Comment: @cricket_007 `Is there a blank identifier in Python as there is in Golang?` Isn't the question in python? haha confused here

Comment: @RafaelC Maybe I am confused :/